# Java CashRegister class Total Sales will not add up correctly

Tags: java

I am just about finished with a basic Cash Register program.  Almost everything is working except the very end of the output where I have to show the daily total sales.

Cash Register class

```
public class CashRegister
{
   private double purchase;
   private double payment;
   private double totalTax;
   private double taxRate;
   private double tax;
   private double salesTotal;
   private double salesCount;
   private double amount;
   private double rate;
   private double taxPurchase;
   private double taxable;
   /**
   Constructs a cash register with no money in it.
   */
   public CashRegister(double rate)
   {
      purchase = 0;
      payment = 0;
     taxRate = rate;
   }
   /**
   Records the sale of an item.
   @param amount the price of the item
   */
   public void recordPurchase(double amount)
   {
      purchase = purchase + amount;
     salesTotal = amount + salesTotal;
   }
   /**
   Records the sale of a taxable item and compute the total tax.
   @param amount the price of the item
   */
   public void recordTaxablePurchase(double amount)
   {
     //taxPurchase = taxPurchase + amount;
      totalTax = totalTax +  amount + (amount* (taxRate / 100));
    }

   /**
   Enters the payment received from the customer.
   @param amount the amount of the payment
   */
   public void enterPayment(double amount)
   {
      payment = amount;

   }
   /**
   Returns the total tax due
   @return the totalTax 
   */
   public double getTotalTax()
   {

      return totalTax;
   }
   /**
   Computes the change due and resets the machine for the next customer.
   @return the change due to the customer
   */
   public double giveChange()
   {
      double change = payment - purchase - totalTax;
     salesTotal += purchase;
      purchase = 0;
      payment = 0;
     //totalTax = 0;
     salesCount++;
     salesTotal++;
      return change;
    }

   public double getSalesTotal(){
      return purchase + totalTax;

   }

   public double getSalesCount(){
      return salesCount;
   }

   public void reset(){
      amount = 0;
      purchase = 0;
      totalTax = 0;
      salesTotal = 0;
      salesCount = 0;
   }
   public double showPayment(){
      return payment;
   }

   public double getTotalPurchase(){
      return payment + totalTax;
   }
}
```

The Cash Register tester class

```
public class CashRegisterTester{
   public static void main(String [] args){

   CashRegister cash1 = new CashRegister(7.5);
      System.out.println("Customer 1:");
      cash1.recordPurchase(20.00);
      cash1.enterPayment(20.00);
      System.out.println(" Change is: " + cash1.giveChange());
      System.out.println(" Expected is 0.0");

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Customer 2:");
      cash1.recordPurchase(30.00);
      cash1.recordPurchase(10.00);
      cash1.enterPayment(50.00);
      System.out.println(" Change is: " + cash1.giveChange());
      System.out.println(" Expected is 10.0"); 

      //cash1.reset();
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Customer 3:");
      cash1.recordTaxablePurchase(80.00);
      cash1.recordPurchase(70.00);
      cash1.recordTaxablePurchase(50.00);
      cash1.enterPayment(220.00);     
      System.out.println(" Total Sales: " + cash1.getSalesTotal());
      System.out.println(" Payment Given: " + cash1.showPayment());
      System.out.println(" Change is: " + cash1.giveChange());
      System.out.println(" Expected is: 7.0");

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println(" Daily Totals: ");
      System.out.println(" Total Sales:   " + "$ " + cash1.getSalesTotal());
      System.out.println(" Number of Sales:  " + cash1.getSalesCount());

   }



}
```

The current output is :

```
Customer 1:
 Change is: 0.0
 Expected is 0.0

Customer 2:
 Change is: 10.0
 Expected is 10.0

Customer 3:
 Total Sales: 209.75
 Payment Given: 220.0
 Change is: 10.25
 Expected is: 7.0

 Daily Totals: 
 Total Sales:   $ 139.75
 Number of Sales:  3.0
```

Everything is correct except for the total sales under Daily Totals, which should be 269.75.  I am confused as to why this will not work.  Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `giveChange()` you're resetting your purchase amounts back to 0. Your `giveSalesCount` therefore is only returning the total purchases that are totalled from your taxable sales.

Either store the payment amount elsewhere when you're calculating the change or find another way to make that calculation without removing your purchases.